# why is the span of a group action invarient isomorphic to C

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

We are working on isotypic decomposition, we have $G$ a group, and $V$ a $G$-module over $\mathbb{C}$. I have the statement that

$v \in V^G = \{v \in V : g.v=v$  for all  $g \in G\}\iff$span$(v)\cong \mathbb{C}$.

Why is this true? Is it a trivial fact about invariants?

Comment: Which direction of the iff isn't obvious to you?

Answer (score 1):

By $V$ is a "$G$-module over $\mathbb{C}$", you probably mean that $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module and then $v$ being invariant under the $G$ action means that the span over $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is the same as the span over $\mathbb{C}$, which is a one-dimensional vector space.

For the converse direction to be true, I think you need to replace $g.v=v$ by $g.v=\lambda v$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.